# imap is not connecting to mail server from live server but working fine from localhost

Tags: php, imap

I could connect to a mail server from my localserver my when I uploaded that file to a server I am getting the following error

Notice: Unknown: rsh to IMAP server timed out (errflg=1) in Unknown on line 0

Notice: Unknown: Connection failed to mail.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.com,143: Connection refused (errflg=2) in Unknown on line 0

Please help Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using the ip address to connect instead of the domain name (mail.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.com).

Comment: but I am able to connect to the server from my local server, problem only with live server

Comment: I came across this problem too. Keep in mind you *should* be able to use a local IP such as `127.0.0.1`.

Answer (score 0):

Is your server behind a firewall or a NAT router ? Otherwise does it resolve to the same IP when you try to look it up from the remote and local host ? Check with:

> nslookup mail.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.com

Comment: but I am able to connect to the server from my local server, problem only with live server

Comment: Do the IP addresses for mail.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.com differ from your local host and on the server ? Try nslookup or ping

Answer (score 0):

Server may miss or have broken libraries.

If you have a ssh-connection at server you could try to open an IMAP-connection over telnet. (Initiated from server).

Just google "telnet imap" and try a login. If success, library error, if no success. Firewall?